# How do you structure your Backbone + RequireJS applications?

Tags: backbone.js, structure, requirejs

I've been struggling trying to strike the right balance between reusability and complexity when it comes to organizing my Backbone objects into AMD's (for medium- to large-scale applications)

(A) Should every Backbone object (models, views, etc) be in their own module?
(B) Should related Backbone objects be in the same AMD module? (ie: PersonModel, PersonCollection, PersonView objects in the same module definition)

Option (A) seems to allow the most flexibility and reusability, but also the most complexity because of the (potentially) high number of files. While option (B) may make it easier to manage things, but less flexible and really difficult to unit test.

How is (or has) everyone else structured these things?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a correct answer to this question although my preference is to make each model, view, and collection its own module. And yes, you'll have a high number of files (don't forget your template files! :-) but it's not that big a problem for me. I just make sure my file names give me a clue as to what larger context they're in and place all related files into appropriate folders. After about 250 lines of code, things get hard to read anyway so 1 module per Backbone model, view, collection ends up being a lot easier to manage.

Comment: I've just tried out Backbone a little bit. But I think number of files is important for performance (too many files and round-trips to server will skyrocket). So, maybe you can try to maintain things modular, and when you build for production, use some kind of "compiler" (Closure maybe?) to reduce and combine JS file size.

Comment: Helios: RequireJS can do that. http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I good thing about requirejs is that it allow you to abstract the physical files into structured namespaces. You can take the approach (A) and create each backbone class in their own file, then create a "namespace" module to glue all the related classes together.

```
// Suppose you have PersonView.js, PersonCollectionjs, PersonModel.js as modules
// create a Person module to function as namespace
define(["PersonModel", "PersonCollection", "PersonView"], function(model, collection, view) {
     return {
        Model: model,
        Collection: collection,
        View: view
     };  
});
```

This keep the modules organized in their own files and gives you some flexibility to write one module per class without requiring you to expose this organization for the rest of the application (I really don't like to have to write `require("PersonView", "PersonModel" ... )` every time I need to use the person's objects, it's easier and cleaner for consumers to declare a dependency on a "namespace" instead of independent classes).

Comment: thanks devundef - I was toying with this idea as well. this seems to make the most sense for my current implementation. this way this are a bit more simplified for the "consumer" but the modularity is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

For medium to large backbone projects I prefer to use requirejs with a separate module for every model, collection, and view. I also use the "Text" plugin for requirejs so I can load underscore templates just as I would any other module. This for me seems to be the sanest way to manage a large project and I have never really felt overwhelmed with the number of files I have.

+1 on using the requirejs optimizer when pushing your app to production. Works really well.
http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

I just released an open source toolkit which will hopefully help others as much as it helps me. It is a composition of many open source tools which gives you a working requirejs backbone app out of the box.

It provides single commands to run: dev web server, jasmine single browser test runner, jasmine js-test-driver multi browser test runner, and concatenization/minification for JavaScript and CSS. It also outputs an unminified version of your app for production debugging, precompiles your handlebar templates, and supports internationalization.

No setup is required. It just works.

http://github.com/davidjnelson...

Comment: cool - but you forgot to mention the name of the project :-)  Unless you're talking about Yeomen.